# Google Places webservice returns nextpage token as 0x0 after two requests

Tags: google-places-api, d

I have written a d code to retrieve the available places (like hospitals in US) from google places web service. I am able to retrieve place details only continuously for 2 requests only. afterwards the pagination token is set as 0x0 in the json response.

But if i manually do the search in the google then it keep on moving more than that. What is wrong am i doing here. Google says that it allows 1000 request per day limit for free. But it doesn't serve more than 2 requests. I have used d lang "requests" module for making the http request.

Comment: Have you already checked the log output of requests? Maybe you need to set a proper user agent? Does Google explicitly allow crawlers? Seems more like they recognize that you are doing it automatically and blocking you.

Comment: the "requests" http api sets "dlang client" as default user agent. I have already searched methods to set user-agent in the request. But i couldn't find any methods in "requests" api. Also I have set the time interval for the crawling.

Comment: I have set the user-agent as well but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get 60 results across three pages, because that's the maximum provided by the API.

Nearby Search and Text Search requests in the Google Places API web service return a maximum of 60 results.  See the [Accessing Additional Results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging) section of the documentation, which says:

> each search can return as many as **60 results**, split across three pages.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks for your information and link to documentation. It solves my question. But Is it possible to retrieve more results like what we seen in the normal google maps search. Because in normal maps if we search "Hospital in CHENNAI" then it returns around 230 records but not in the case of web service request. what is the actual reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

dlang-requests can display (to stdout) detailed info on request and response if you use verbosity=3.
Also you can compile sources it with -debug=requests and set globalLogLevel(LogLevel.trace) to produce even more detailed log information. If this doesn't help, then please give me detailed info on failed API call so that I can reproduce problem.